# Formik fieldarray name nested three levels deep

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, string-interpolation

Hoping to get some help based on below initial values. This is just a snippet of my data but I am trying to perform a Formik FieldArray at the `itinerary` level, nested three levels deep but unsure what the name to assign for this FieldArray name.

```
{itineraryGroups[itineraryDetails].map((idetail, index) => (

            <FieldArray
            name={`itineraryGroups.${index}.itineraryDetails.itinerary`}          
            render={(arrayHelpers) => (
              <React.Fragment>
                    {idetail.itinerary.map((i, idx) => (
```

Just not sure what my FieldArray name should be at the `itinerary` level as this is not working: **name={`itineraryGroups.${index}.itineraryDetails.itinerary`}**

Obviously here, `itineraryDetails` is also an array, so not sure if this will also need a array index.

The below is my initial values setup:

```
const itineraryGroup = {
          itineraryName: "",
          itineraryDetails: [
            {
              day: "Monday",
              itinerary: [
                {
                    day: "Day 1",
                    description: "description one"               
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              day: "Tuesday",
              itinerary: [
                {
                    day: "Day 2",
                    description: "description two",               
                }
              ]
            }                                                                       
          ]
      };
      
      
const INITIAL_FORM_STATE = {
  name: '',
  itineraryGroups: [itineraryGroup]
};

    <Formik
      enableReinitialize
      initialValues={{ 
        ...INITIAL_FORM_STATE
      }}
```

Comment: you declare `itineraryGroups` is an array: `itineraryGroups: [itineraryGroup]`, but you use it as an object: `itineraryGroups.itineraryDetails`?

Comment: @Viet - good pick up and have corrected, but my question is further down the track with regards to getting down to `itinerary` for FieldArray name.

Comment: You need to clear about your data, then I can help you

Comment: Sure @Viet - what exactly is not clear pls?

Comment: I want clear `itineraryGroups` is an array `itineraryGroups: [itineraryGroup]` or you wnat it is an object: `itineraryGroups: itineraryGroup`?

Comment: @Viet - definitely an array, i.e.: `itineraryGroups: [itineraryGroup]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `itineraryGroups` is an array with only 1 element like you declare, you can update like this:

```
{itineraryGroups[0].itineraryDetails.map((idetail, index) => ( 

  <FieldArray
  name={`itineraryGroups[0].itineraryDetails[${index}].itinerary`}          
  render={(arrayHelpers) => (
    <React.Fragment>
          {idetail.itinerary.map((i, idx) => (
```

**Update**: If `itineraryGroups` has multi elements, You need to add more `map`:

```
{itineraryGroups.map((iGroup, indexGroup) => (
  {iGroup.itineraryDetails.map((idetail, index) => ( 
    <FieldArray
      name={`itineraryGroups[${indexGroup}].itineraryDetails[${index}].itinerary`}
```

Comment: I should've also added that `itineraryGroups` is also a FieldArray within my app as there can be 1-M itineraryGroups. I assume this will require another index from the top to be passed down?

Comment: Yes. You add another index. I updated my comment

Comment: Actually Viet, based on the above as I'm still having trouble, how can I access `day` within the `itinerary` array?

Comment: You can use `i.day` in `{idetail.itinerary.map((i, idx) => ())}`

Comment: so would it be: `name={`${i}.day`}` ?

Comment: For name, you need use: `itineraryGroups[${indexGroup}].itineraryDetails[${index}].itinerary[${idx}].day`